# How do I escape POST body correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, http

I need to send some JSON values to the server using POST requests; sending them without any escaping works fine, but this is not a proper solution as these values might contain special symbols like ? and &.
I've tried answers from another questions (Uri.EscapeDataString, Uri.EscapeUriString, System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode, System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode) but they all make the server return a "Bad request" error.
How can I escape POST values **properly**?

Comment: `?` and `&` are fine in JSON, as far as I can think. But your concerns are valid, all the same. How are you serializing the JSON? If you're using a library--pretty well any library--it should handle the escaping itself. If you're building the string yourself, that's a bit more of a challenge, but I *believe* the only concern is double-quotes, which can be escaped with a backslash. But realistically, I'd heavily advise use of a library unless performance is critical and usage is low. It'll just be more robust.

Comment: @Matthew Haugen, what I'm concerned about is validity of my data as *POST request body*

Comment: An HTTP request body (POST or otherwise) is just bytes, the length of which is determined by the `Content-Length` header (or something to that effect, if chunked encoding is in use). You don't have to worry about anything being escaped for that to work, escaping only comes into play at the next level up, the content type.

Comment: @ Matthew Haugen, well... and how should I encode my data with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type to be read by server correctly?

Comment: So you'd like to nest your JSON within the form? That's reasonable, albeit a tad unorthodox. I don't know of any services off-hand that do that. But in that case, I believe `Uri.EscapeDataString` should be doing what you need. If that's giving you a `400 Bad Request`, are you sure that's what the server is expecting?

Comment: @ Matthew Haugen, I'm not sure what the server is expecting as it's not documented well. It seems it just ignores content type and assumes it's always "application/json", what probably means I don't need any encoding.

Comment: In most modern APIs ("most" and "modern" are up for interpretation there), JSON is a pretty reasonable expectation, yeah. So then we go back to my first comment, and say that you'd only *really* have to worry about escaping within the JSON elements themselves, and if you're using a library, that should be handled for you. You decidedly don't want to double-encode, for obvious reasons. The quick way of testing your entire setup, of course, is just to try and submit regular data (the control) and make sure it works, then submit something with a double-quote, and if you want, a question mark.

Comment: @ Matthew Haugen, well, this probably answers my question.

Comment: I posted an answer that (I hope) summarizes the key points from these comments. Definitely let me know if I can clarify anything or if I didn't fully answer your question, and I'd be happy to edit it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After our little chat in comments, I think I know enough about what you're asking to put together an answer. So here goes.

I see three marginally-distinct questions being asked.

1. How can one escape an HTTP `POST` request's body?

I'll quote from my comment on this, since it's pretty complete.

> An HTTP request body (POST or otherwise) is just bytes, the length of which is determined by the Content-Length header (or something to that effect, if chunked encoding is in use). You don't have to worry about anything being escaped for that to work, escaping only comes into play at the next level up, the content type.

Essentially, there's no native requirement for any sort of escaping for a vanilla POST to go through.

2. How do `application/json` and `application/x-www-formurl-encoded` play together?

In most cases, they just don't. They can, and I think I've seen it done before, but I can't really think of why you'd want to.

Just for background, and to make sure we're on the same page, here's the same object, serialized to JSON and form data respectively.

Plain object (for comparison):

```
PropertyName: The value is "1 & 2"
OtherProperty: 2
```

JSON:

```
{
    "PropertyName" : "The value is \"1 & 2\"",
    "OtherProperty" : 2
}
```

Form data:

```
PropertyName=The%20value%20is%20%221%20%26%202%22&OtherProperty=2
```

That value got pretty messy, as you can see. But you get the point.

So, yes, you could quite reasonably nest one in the other, but there aren't many use-cases where that would make any sense.

3. How do I escape JSON?

If you're using a library, that library should (if it's worth anything) do this for you. JSON.net will, for example. I believe the only thing you'd have to worry about escaping are double-quotes in JSON, but I'm no expert, and it wouldn't surprise me to learn there were edge-cases.

I'll quote again from my comment, since it seems to have helped you.

> In most modern APIs ("most" and "modern" are up for interpretation there), JSON is a pretty reasonable expectation, yeah. So then we go back to my first comment, and say that you'd only really have to worry about escaping within the JSON elements themselves, and if you're using a library, that should be handled for you. You decidedly don't want to double-encode, for obvious reasons.
>
> The quick way of testing your entire setup, of course, is just to try and submit regular data (the control) and make sure it works, then submit something with a double-quote, and if you want, a question mark.

If you run that test and the second fails, there's a good chance something's not being property escaped. That might be a nice time to either use debugging tools, or even just an application like Fiddler to inspect the request payload for anything unreasonable, for example, if your JSON looked like `{ "name":"val"ue" }`